# Join in Couchbase Lite, how is it possible?

Tags: couchbase-lite

Consider two types of documents `Company` and `Person`:

`Company` has 2 fields:

- `name` of type `String`
- `employees` of type `List of Person`

`Person` has 2 fields:

- `name` of type `String`
- `city` of type `String`

How can I create a query where I find all the companies who have at least `N` employees in a given city ?

EDIT: In other words, How is it possible to do something like [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries) with CouchBase Lite.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several ways to approach this.

One suggestion is to create a view that, when given a Company document, emits a key/value pair via the map stage.  The key could be a map containing the company name and city, and the value could be anything (e.g. employee name).  Then add a reduce function that sums all the index entries (that's what the first part creates) with the same key.

So the result of the reduce stage output for the view is the total number of employees keyed by company + city.  You can then do queries to get your result.

Views and Queries are really powerful, but can take some thought.  Focus on getting the information you need out of the View, so you can query flexibly.

Take a look at the [View](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/view/index.html) and [Query](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/query/index.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks, for now I switched to Realm (because join is easier there), if it seems to be too painful then I might switch back to CouchBase.

Comment: @jhegedus Couchbase Mobile v2.0 will have N1QL (superset of SQL) which will simplify this a lot.  Couchbase is releasing previews and looking for feedback.  Take a look if you have a chance.  Thanks.